# Running mssh: No user exists for uid 1000

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My Dockerfile and Jenkinsfile are currently set up like this.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install ec2instanceconnectcli
```

Jenkinsfile snippet:

```
     stage('Initialize Docker'){
        steps{
            script{
            def dockerHome = tool 'myDocker'
            env.PATH = "${dockerHome}/bin:${env.PATH}"
            }
        }
    }

    stage('EC2 Connection'){
       
        agent{
            dockerfile true
            }
 
        steps{
            withAWS(credentials: '********', region: 'us-east-2') {
                   sh 'mssh ************ --region us-east-2'
           }
        }
        
    }
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error:

```
+ mssh ************ --region us-east-2
No user exists for uid 1000
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to solve this by ensuring a user at UID 1000, or by executing the SSH protocol with a different user? Either would solve the error here.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, but I think ensuring a user at UID 1000 would be fine.

Comment: I received this new error when I added the user, have you dealt with this before?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974048/running-mssh-pseudo-terminal-will-not-be-allocated-because-stdin-is-not-a-termi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image tag `python:3.7` is equivalent to `3.7.13-bullseye`, so we are working with the latest version of Debian here. Debian requires use of `adduser` for adding a new user. We can modify your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install ec2instanceconnectcli && adduser --uid 1000 jenkins
```

will create the equivalent `jenkins` user inside the image for the agent. The expected `jenkins` user for the `sh` step method will then exist.

Note the `jenkins` user also has e.g. shell set to `/sbin/nologin`, and you can incrementally modify for this extra security if it does not break functionality.